# Please help configure JBoss 7 “mail-session” via jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I need to create smtp Mail connector via `jboss-cli` command line. So far I've managed to create `<mail-session>` and `<smtp-server>` nodes in configuration xml:

```
/subsystem=mail/mail-session="java:/mail/myMail":add(jndi-name="java:/mail/myMail", from="noreply@acme.com")
/subsystem=mail/mail-session="java:/mail/myMail"/server=smtp:add
```

All the above resulted in the following part in configuration file:

```
<!-- default JBoss session with auth data -->
<mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
  <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
    <login name="user" password="pass"/>
  </smtp-server>
</mail-session>
<!-- Created mail session -->
<mail-session jndi-name="java:/mail/myMail" from="noreply@acme.com">
  <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
     <!-- no login node -->
  </smtp-server>
</mail-session>
```

After playing with GUI Admin console I found that `<smtp-server>` node should contain `<login name="login" password="pass">` child node, but I have no idea how to do it, JBoss Admin guide has no clues on the subject. If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not too familiar with the subsystem, but have you tried the tab complete? Just type in something like `/subsystem=mail/mail-session="java:/mail/myMail":add(` then use the tab key to see the options. Also you can use `/subsystem=mail/mail-session=*:read-resource-description` to see the available options.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, it worked, thanks! Btw I've tried tab key after `:add`, not `:add(`, and got no complete suggestions ))

Comment: James nailed it... tab completion rocks for filling the paths and exposing the available Commands and Operations for a resource node. You can use the `read-resource` operation to expose attributes, `add` to add them, and `write` to write them. All in all a pretty easy process thanks to tab completion!

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=940) could give you some ideas

Answer (score 1):

This commands add username and password for default session (change session name in command as needed)

```
/subsystem=mail/mail-session=java\:jboss\/mail\/Default/server=smtp/:write-attribute(name=username,value=your-username)

/subsystem=mail/mail-session=java\:jboss\/mail\/Default/server=smtp/:write-attribute(name=password,value=you-password)
```